# Powerfx code to hide/show ribbon button in main form when the dropdown is selected in powerapp form

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, power-platform, powerapps-modeldriven

need hide/show the button in main form when the dropdown is selected for the particular value

Here is the what i tried

```
If(Self.Selected.Item.Logicalname='Logicalname'.Dropdownvalue, true, false)
```